# Change nav padding using javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the padding of ul li a to fit inside the window as the window is made smaller.

What I'm trying to accomplish: www.seu.edu (main nav)

What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/RHwwq/5/

```
 $(document).resize(function() {
    var wide = parseFloat($('nav.main').css('width'));
    var newMargin = wide/5;
    newMargin = (newMargin/2)+'px';
    $('nav.main ul li a').css('padding-left',newMargin);
    $('nav.main ul li a').css('padding-right',newMargin);

    }

});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is not working like you expect? Don't forget you have a `min-width`.

Comment: You've asked about JavaScript, but you've written jQuery. Since jQuery isn't included in your Fiddle, it's not working: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Need to include the jQuery library to make it work. Also you have a extra closing brace which will cause a syntax error.

Comment: @isherwood, `OP` should have mentioned `jQuery` but it's still now `JavaScript` and valid to call it `javaScript`.

Comment: @Sushanth--, `jQuery` is a function library not a `framework`, IMO.

Comment: @SheikhHeera.. my  bad corrected it.. Thanks for pointing it out. I was referring to the frameworks section in jsfiddle and was not my intent to say it was a framwork :)

Comment: Pedantry aside, the fiddle works if jQuery is included.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a javascript question but you can accomplish this much simpler by using either media queries or box-sizing + padding.

USING MEDIA QUERIES:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    padding:0px 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    padding:0px 20px;
}
```

USING BOX-SIZING:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:0 0.5em; // OR percentage, pt whatever.
```

this I feel would be a more long lasting and easy to manage solution than to do a function for each resize. EM or % should be used as this is relative to the device it's being viewed on and therefore scales it better. What box-sizing:border-box does is encapsulate the padding into the total width of whatever your element is. That way you have to just set and forget rather than worry about overflowing your container.

Hope this is helpful, but if its not what you were looking for no worries :)

Comment: Thanks! Shalom

I tried steering away from media queries just because I didn't want it to jump but rather change based fluidly like in the menu on www.seu.edu  

This is what I have now 'nav.main{
    height:61px;
    margin-top:39px;
 /*min-width: 1260px;*/
}

nav.main ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

nav.main ul li{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:12px 2.4%;
}

nav.main ul li a{
    color:white;
    font-size:1.611em;
    font-weight:100;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:0 0.5em;
}
'  Stil doesn't work thought

Comment: give me a bit and I'll create a fiddle for you :)

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the slow reply. A Box-sizing solution would look sort of like this http://jsfiddle.net/6sJVb/

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra brace

```
$(document).resize(function() {
    var wide = parseFloat($('nav.main').css('width'));
    var newMargin = wide/5;
    newMargin = (newMargin/2)+'px';
    $('nav.main ul li a').css('padding-left',newMargin);
    $('nav.main ul li a').css('padding-right',newMargin);

    } // <------ remove this

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$(window).resize` not `$(document).resize`, in your example, event is not triggering, you may try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var wide = $('nav.main').width();
    var newMargin = wide/5;
    newMargin = (newMargin/2)+'px';
    $('nav.main ul li a').css('padding-left',newMargin);
    $('nav.main ul li a').css('padding-right',newMargin);
});
```

[**Updated Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RHwwq/4/)

Also, `css media query` is prefered way for responsiveness. You got an answer already, consider to use this, answered by `Shalom Aptekar`.